# determine the path to save file

Tags: python

I saw the script here a short while ago this is

```
i = 1
while i <= 10:
    with open("{}.txt".format(i), "w") as f:
       f.write("content")
    i += 1
```

I have a question about it: how do you determine the path to save files?

Pleas add the code off path in the script

Answer (score 2):

You're opening the files in the current working directory, which you can find with `os.getcwd()` (after `import os`).

If you want to use some other path, then you can use something like `open("/path/to/something/{}.txt".format(i),"w")`, or, more reliably, `open(os.path.join( yourpath, "{}.txt".format(i),"w")` for a path in `yourpath`.

With that said, while loops of incrementing values are generally not considered good form in python. I'd suggest

```
for i in range(1,11): # range doesn't include the last value
    with open("{}.txt".format(i), 'w') as f:
        f.write("content")
```